# How to prevent an automatic height row from expanding in a CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I currently have a very simple design with three areas arranged vertically similar to header-body-foot. The central area has automatic overflow and looks like this:

[image: three areas]

And when the height of the content of the central area exceeds the height of the container:

[image: three areas and a scrollbar in second]

In previous version of the site, the height of the upper and lower areas is fixed on pixels and the height of the central area I obtain calculating `calc(100vh - 24px - 80px)` (simplifying).

Now I am converting all the layout of the site to CSS Grid, which has been in general quite easy. However on this simple page I have not been able to achieve that the central area of the grid has automatic height with respect to the browser window and, at the same time, show the scrollbar when the content exceeds this height.

This is a simplified html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='area1'>
        Toolbar
      </div>
      <table class='area2'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
            <td>Cell content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
            <td>Cell content 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
            <td>Cell content 3</td>
          </tr>

          <!--append here many rows-->

        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class='area3'>
        Details
      </div>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh; /*I need to respect always this height*/
    display: grid;
    gap: 2px;
    grid-template-rows: 24px 1fr 80px;
    grid-template-areas: "area1" "area2" "area3";
}
.area1 {
    grid-area: area1;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.area2 {
    grid-area: area2;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.area3 {
    grid-area: area3;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

With this new layout and a large amount of table rows, the central area (the table) expands downward instead of being with a fixed height and a scrollbar, like this:

[image: second area expanded]

What I need is:

- The central area must always keep the same height, and must show a scrollbar if needed.
- The lower area must always be visible in the browser window (as in the two images of the beginning).

I have also tried it with `grid-template-rows: 24px minmax(100px, 1fr) 80px` and   `24px auto 80px`.

Is there any way to get it using CSS Grid?

Comment: 1. you forgot `;`/semicolon on your `grid-template-areas`. 2. You don't need `grid-template-areas` for such a simple layout, you could just use `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` in addition to your `grid-template-rows`

Comment: Is what you've called Column 2 actually Row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the table itself. It's not adapting well to grid layout (at least in this case).

I suggest you wrap the table in a div, making the div the grid item.

Seems to work now.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  /*I need to respect always this height*/
  display: grid;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-template-rows: 24px 1fr 80px;
  grid-template-areas: 
          "area1"
          "area2"
          "area3";
}

.area1 {
  grid-area: area1;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.area2 {
  grid-area: area2;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.area3 {
  grid-area: area3;
  border: solid 1px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='area1'>
    Toolbar
  </div>
  <div class="area2">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
          <td>Cell content 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
          <td>Cell content 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class='area3'>
    Details
  </div>
  <div>
```